# sbt-native-packager with Akka example

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

Any distribution example for Akka application using SBT and sbt-native-packager? I managed to use  akka-sbt-plugin to package the entire application into a runnable server for distribution. Now, I am struggling to do the same with this plugin because akka-sbt-plugin is been replaced by sbt-native-packager. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example https://gist.github.com/tobym/3665514fde79eaab8724

Basically, just include `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.8.0-M1")`
 in `project/plugins.sbt`, and in `build.sbt` import `com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._` and `NativePackagerKeys._`.

Then run `rpm:packageBin` (or another option, such as debian...this depends on your deploy target) and fill in the missing settings in `build.sbt` until it works. For rpm, you'll need to have the rpm tools available. On mac, you can get this with `sudo port install rpm`.

Comment: Thanks. I use version 1.0.0M4 with sbt 0.13.5 so this may not apply directly and I have that figured out.